# Match all lines with a pattern after a text until pattern matching failure regex

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I have a text:

```
{{Verkleinerungsformen}}
:[1] [[Äpfelchen]], [[Äpfelein]], [[Äpflein]]

{{Oberbegriffe}}
:[1] [[Kernobst]], [[Obst]]; [[Frucht]]
:[4] [[Kot]]
:[7] [[Gut]]

{{Unterbegriffe}}
:[1] [[Augustapfel]], [[Bohnapfel]], [[Bratapfel]], [[Essapfel]], [[Fallapfel]],
```

I'm interested in extracting all items under `{{Oberbegriffe}}` that have the pattern [[Text]]
including all lines until it reach another line that does not have `:[NUMBER-HERE]` at the begin

so in the above example it should return an array of these strings:

`Kernobst, Obst, Frucht, Kot, Gut`

what I have tried is:

`re.search(r'{{Oberbegriffe}}\n(?::?\n)?([^\n]+)', text)`

But it matches only the full first line. It's ok if there is a way to extract all lines with the pattern and it retruns this  string

```
:[1] [[Kernobst]], [[Obst]]; [[Frucht]]
:[4] [[Kot]]
:[7] [[Gut]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract the blocks using

```
(?m)^{{Oberbegriffe}}(?:\n:\[\d+].*)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1rWheR/1)

Then, use `\[\[([^][]+)]]` pattern to extract the values you need. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ljwfk5/1).

**Regex details**

- `(?m)` - an inline modifier, same as `re.M` / `re.MULTILINE`
- `^` - start of a line
- `{{Oberbegriffe}}`  - literal text
- `(?:\n:\[\d+].*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of a newline followed with `:[`, then 1+ digits, `]`, and then any 0 or more characters other than line break chars, as many as possible.

The second regex - `\[\[([^][]+)]]` - matches `[[`, then capturing group #1 matching any 1 or more chars other than `[` and `]`, and then `]]`.

In Python:

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as fr:
  blocks = re.findall(r'^{{Oberbegriffe}}(?:\n:\[\d+].*)*', fr.read(), flags=re.M)
  print([re.findall(r'\[\[([^][]+)]]', block) for block in blocks])
```

Comment: I tried to come up with a PyPi regex approach, but I found it a bit harder to both write the pattern and then collect the right matches per block (see [here](https://tio.run/##bZFNa8JAEIbv/oqtF3eJCNJCQSnSQvVQiqf2sruBqJNkaZwN@wEW663/rD8snai1ofQ2z@w773xs/R5Ki9dNY7a1dYE5KGDXC7AL7I71Fe73r@DeKjAILmLhc@u2gIeDwokcaybl12edQ7UuAbUeXpj0v3giha3bcgVuBYUzeQ4dlydwaFc@nIqWx2hK0dzFdRna4om8OQrtmW5bWsTwY/yC4V/n@1hEH7J2qJP5gy2xiy7rvj5636F5VlUXVNjv0XnoLscjjdZ2W5sKuBvw2UQt@OwqFR/p3xUFTaKk2iSaVHI41TPJVNAJ5SSXqZY6EVqLZDA82z4L6uJjFTx1ktQmq0OkDB8LRtdnO2awlY5ygxtDS/P2t4Tu1c5g4Oda0TTf))

Comment: Interesting to see a one step solution !  the solution in the answer was good enough for my use case.